# Confused with Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors and Vector transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

Hello fellow mathematicians, I am studding " Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors " at this point and I need to understand something here:

I am actually performing automatic operations on finding them, but I don't really understand what they are and what they are used for.

Those operations really look like transformations. What is the difference of transforming a matrix and finding its Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues anyway?

Thank you

Comment: Those descriptions are not what eigenvectors and eigenvalues are, so that might explain it.

Comment: But, we actually perform a transformation over the matrix and then we get a new matrix from that tranformation?

Comment: No, we do not do anything to a matrix when we discuss eigenvectors and eigenvalues. We are given a specific matrix (which is the same as a linear transformation), and we look to see if there are eigenvectors for that matrix. To each of these eigenvectors we then associate an eigenvalue.

Comment: @themhz it doesn't matter how you get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. What matters is what they are. They are not what you describe in your question.

Comment: are you just asking about the reason for the word 'eigen' in eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: oh well yes, I actually thought that because I am doing some operations over a matrix A and I get some new vectors and make a new matrix, seem to me that I am performing a transformation. Forgive me but I am actually performing those operations automatically and I don't really understand what I am doing.. So yes in a way I need to understand Why did we pick those words to.

Comment: I think what themz is confused about is computing the diagonal matrix $D$ and transformation matrix $Q$ associated with a matrix $A$ such that $A=QDQ^{-1}$, which is what he is effectively computing all the time on the one hand. And on the other hand what the notions of eigenvector and eigenvalues have to do with it. Well, the matrix $D$ has the eigenvalues on its diagonal. The matrix $Q$ has the corresponding eigenvectors as columns.

Comment: hehe, yea I am totally confused indeed @Raskolnikov. I think that if I understand where we use this then probably I will understand it better..

Comment: The way you have edited the question has made nonsense out of much of the comments and answer. Also, you have invented the word, "confuded".

Comment: I apologize, anyway, it looks like I was in a rush and confused. I will go search and read some more before I ask again XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some rather deep confussion here and I'm not sure from where to start...so just let's:

(1) Eigenvectors are *not* "produced" by a matrix. They are vectors that fulfill a very precise relation wrt an operator/square matrix .

(2) Eigenvalues don't "scale up" transformations/matrices, whether "transformed" or not (what this means in this context). Eigenvalues are scalars that saisfy a certain polynomial equation very closely related to a trasnformation/matrix

(3) Eigenvectors are not trasnformations. Read (1) above.

Eigenvalues/eigenvectors are names proceeding from the german "eigen", meaning (its) "own" or "self", "inherent or proper", etc.

Comment: Thank you. "hey are vectors that fulfill a very precise relation wrt an operator/square matrix ." what relation? what does wrt mean and why does my teacher give me a matrix and then tells me to find the "Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors " in such way that makes me think that I am actually producing a new matrix? I think I understand that the first vector packet as it seems to be the matrix has information of some n vectors in them. Why do I perform these operations?

Comment: The relation is : $$Tv=\lambda v$$ with $\,T\,$ an operator/matrix, $\,v\neq 0\,$ an eigenvector and $\,\lambda\,$ this eigenvector's associated eigenvalue.

Comment: just to drive it home: What eigenvalues and eigenvectors *are*: certain scalars and certain vectors that are obtained from the matrix and which give a *lot* of information about the matrix. They are completely are self-values and self-vectors in the sense that they are derived from within the matrix and portray back on the matrix as an object. Self = eigen.

Comment: wrt = with respect to . The algorithm to find out eigenvalues/eigenvectors for a matrix is a rather simple one, though it can be a lot of work. It is based in the definition of characteristic polynomial (its roots are the eigenvalues), determinants and stuff. Either you haven't yet covered this or else I think you should go over the whole concept again as it seems to me you have some understanding issues with the whole subject.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanx, yes the operation seems very simple indeed. I just practiced it for 1 day and I am done. But I can't understand probably what an eigenvector is probably at all and what is the use of it any way..

Comment: You have literally millions of internet pages that deal with eigenvectors (close to 2 million in google alone), and thousands of books in linear algebra to read from. One of the most outstanding important features of eigenvalues/vectors is that they make things much simpler: if for some vector(s) I have $\,Tv=\lambda v\,$ then this transformation/matrix acts on $\,v\,$ just by simply multipying it by a scalar: it doesn't get simpler than that! There are other aspects, of course: the product of all the eigenvalues is the matrix's determinant, their sum is the trace, spectral radius and stuff...

Comment: So when I transform a matrix I actually change it. But when I find it's eigenvectors and values, I am actually pointing to a new thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "transform a matrix", @themhz ? I really don't understand you.

Comment: well given a matrix which is a packet of vectors, I am asked to do some operations to create a new matrix that is consisted of it's eigenvectors, so basically it looks like a transformation "just because I am producing a new matrix"

Comment: No, a matrix is not a "package of vectors"...In some circunstances and/or for some rather precise and important applications, you can think of the matrix's rows or columns as vectors in some vector space $\,\Bbb F^n\,\;,\;\;\Bbb F\;$ a field . When it is possible to form a new matrix out of the eigenvectors of another matrix (and not always is this possible!), it is for some precise and clear reason, say: to diagonalize the original matrix. I sincerely think you should read this stuff from scratch because I think you're confusing stuff big time here.

Comment: Yep, indeed. I will go back and read some things and use what you told me. Thank you also for telling me other uses of matrices.

Comment: Thanks for noting me that. $+$

Comment: Not sure why this is the correct answer.  It didn't answer the question, rather it just discounted a range of possible answers to the question.

Comment: @Duane Not sure why you ask about this question from almost 6 years ago. I don't remember. Anyway, you can post an answer yourself if you don't think this is good enough. Perhaps the asked still is around and/or someone else can benefit from it now.

Answer (score 1):

I like to imagine a plane of arrows (vectors), which all are mulptiplied by a matrix. All the arrows will tranform and become new arrows (vectors) on the plane. Those arrows which keep their initial direction are eigenarrows and  eigenvalues determine how the arrows scale (shrink or strech). A negative eigenvalue would mean the arrow changes its direction to the opposite it had. All the other arrows on the plane tranform differently:  they are skewed and scaled.

Comment: So basically the initial vectors create a new set of vectors and those are a totally new set on their own right? I mean they are not a transformation (rotation or scale) of the mother vectors. They just produce a new vector set and those eigenvalues scale those eigenvectors?